# Is there any Image Editor available for Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to have an image editor in Eclipse Helios. Is there any plug-in available for the same. I tried to search and got visual editor but its not image editor.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [MyEclipse Java Image Editor](http://www.myeclipseide.com/htmlpages-func-display-pid-309.html), but I don't know:

- if it is available outside of [MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-4.html)
- if it would work with Eclipse3.6.x (Helios), since for now myEclipse is [based on 3.5.x](http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?module=htmlpages&func=display&pid=329)

[image: MyEclipse Image Editor Screenshot]